# How to install cloud software locally for security research

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform

How you can test cloud software locally?

For AWS, there is Localstack, but what about Google Cloud, and Azure?

I want to try it, change a lot of configurations and maybe install some software there, that is why I don't want to use the remote cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK has a number of emulators available:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/functions-framework

hth.